# Load all dataset to Data Flow (ADF)

Tags: azure-data-factory

I want to load all the data, because I want to pivot store column against sales. The dataset is huge, no matter how I adjust Debug setting, only partial data is loaded. If I set up the limit too high (eg: 100000000000), I will get an error message indicating internal error. As a result, I am not able to pivot the table precisely.

I appreciate any insights and comments helping me indicate how to load the whole data to the data flow. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Dataflow data preview is configured primarily as a way to view data samples, not the entire dataset. The best way to view the results of an entire dataset is to execute the dataflow from a debug pipeline and view the output results.

That being said ... whether you are using data preview inside the data flow canvas, or a pipeline debug session, you should use a larger Azure IR when you need to test with large data sizes.

The default Azure IR that is configured out of the box with ADF only provides 4 cores on a single worker node because it is intended to provide debugging and preview of sampled data.

Create a new Azure IR with General Purpose or Memory Optimized and minimum of 32 worker cores, then restart your debug session with this larger compute size.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation. Finally, we reduce the data size before the data is stored in ADF.